# passing ng-model input date to a service to make a api consult

Tags: angularjs

I need to pass a user-selected date from my view to my service.

**View:**

```
<div class='input-group date'>
    <input type="date" ng-model="dateLinea" class="form-control"/>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
function MainCtrl($scope, consumeApi, $filter) {
     consumeApi.getFullByron().success(function(data){
        $scope.dataFromFactory = data;
 });
```

**Factory:**

```
function consumeApi($http) {

    // Return the object
    return {

        // Create simple method to get data from $http service
        getFullByron : function() {
            return $http({
                url: 'http://localhost/proveedores_api/core/api/proveedores/negocio_linea/negocio_linea_proveedor.php?api_key=ff19974921e713dd4ae3a6592532cd9d&function=negocio_linea_fecha&fecha=' + dateLinea,
                method: 'GET'
            })
        }
    }

}
```

The url ends before the date, but I need to include the date that was passed in from the view.

I need to pass `dateLinea` to my service so, when I select a date, that date is added to the url to make the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works for you.

```js
function MainCtrl($scope, consumeApi, $filter) {
//instead of null set this value to the whatever initial page load value needed. 
  $scope.dateLinea = null;

  consumeApi.getFullByron($scope.dateLinea)
   .then(function(data) {
        $scope.dataFromFactory = data;
   })
   .catch(function(err) {
       console.log(err)
   });

  function consumeApi($http) {

    // Return the object
    return {

      // Create simple method to get data from $http service
      getFullByron: function(dateLinea) {
        return $http.get('http://localhost/proveedores_api/core/api/proveedores/negocio_linea/negocio_linea_proveedor.php?api_key=ff19974921e713dd4ae3a6592532cd9d&function=negocio_linea_fecha&fecha=' + dateLinea)
          .then(function(resp) {
          // here you can return the whole response or just data, depending on what you need or other preprocessing.
            return resp.data;
          })
      }
    }

  }
```

EDIT:

```js
function MainCtrl($scope, consumeApi, $filter) {
  //instead of null set this value to the whatever initial page load value needed. 
  $scope.dateLinea = null;

  function exampleGetWrapperFunction() {
    if ($scope.dateLinea) {
      consumeApi.getFullByron($scope.dateLinea)
        .then(function(data) {
          $scope.dataFromFactory = data;
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.log(err)
        });
    }
  }
  exampleGetWrapperFunction();
}
```

Comment: angular.js:13236 TypeError: consumeApi.getFullByron(...).success is not a function
    at new MainCtrl (controllers.js:64)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4604)
    at T.instance (angular.js:9855)
    at u (angular.js:8927)
    at g (angular.js:8226)
    at g (angular.js:8229)
    at angular.js:8106
    at angular.js:1696
    at m.$eval (angular.js:16820)
    at m.$apply (angular.js:16920)

Comment: angular.js:13236 ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at factories.js:14
    at angular.js:15552
    at m.$eval (angular.js:16820)
    at m.$digest (angular.js:16636)
    at m.$apply (angular.js:16928)
    at g (angular.js:11266)
    at t (angular.js:11464)
    at XMLHttpRequest.u.onload (angular.js:11405)

Comment: the app doesnt start and in the console i get this two errors,

Comment: @AndreaSuarez what version of angular are you using, .success is deprecated. ill update with current promise resolve function.

Comment: Thats perfects it does work, thank you very much, i have an aditional consult, how do i do, that when i select a date, it makes the consult in that moment, because now its getting null date on page load,

Comment: Object {data: Object, status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK", headers: function}
config
:
Object
headers
:
Object
method
:
"GET"
paramSerializer
:
function (a)
transformRequest
:
Array(1)
transformResponse
:
Array(1)
url
:
"http://localhost/proveedores_api/core/api/proveedores/negocio_linea/negocio_linea_proveedor.php?api_key=ff19974921e713dd4ae3a6592532cd9d&function=negocio_linea_fecha&fecha=null"
__proto__
:
Object
data
:
Object
headers
:
function (d)
status
:
200
statusText
:
"OK"
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: oh just set the $scope.dateLinea = consult; instead of null or whatever else you need it to be.

Comment: sorry for been such a newbie, but i dont know how to do that, what does the consult means?

Comment: @AndreaSuarez I updated the code with a comment in the scoped variable. just make the scoped var equal to whatever value you need it to be.

Comment: i need that doesnt make the consult unless a date is selected. it can be done?

Comment: @AndreaSuarez  depends add an ng click if your doing it off of a button or like the update piece of code i just added

Comment: @AndreaSuarez if you feel I have answered your question, please consider marking as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass model to API as a parameter and use it in service...

code as below

Controller:

```
function MainCtrl($scope, consumeApi, $filter) {
 consumeApi.getFullByron($scope.dateLinea).success(function(data){
    console.log(data);
    $scope.dataFromFactory = data;
});
```

In Service:

```
function consumeApi($http) {

// Return the object
return {

    // Create simple method to get data from $http service
    getFullByron : function(dateLinea) {
        return $http({
            url: 'http://localhost/proveedores_api/core/api/proveedores/negocio_linea/negocio_linea_proveedor.php?api_key=ff19974921e713dd4ae3a6592532cd9d&function=negocio_linea_fecha&fecha=' + dateLinea,
            method: 'GET'
        })
    }
  }

}
```